# Python- recursion with printing

Tags: python, list, recursion, printing

I need to print the elements of list, such that if an element is 100 or greater, it's followed by a newline, and if not, it's followed by a space.

This is what I have so far:

```
def function(list):
    if list == []:
        return None
    elif list[0] >= 100:
        print(list[0], function(list[1:]), end = '\n')
    else:
        print(list[0], function(list[1:]), end = '')
    return None
```

But when I try list = [2,3,103, 8, 10],
Python prints:

> 10 None8 None103 None
>
> 3 None2 None

Any suggestions/help?

Comment: The problem is that you're printing the function call's returns as well. Put the recursive calls outside of the print statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. This is what you want:

```
def function(lst):
    if not lst:
        return
    elif lst[0] >= 100:
        print(lst[0], end='\n')
    else:
        print(lst[0], end=' ')
    function(lst[1:])
```

(I renamed `list` to `lst` because `list` is a builtin type that we don't want to overwrite).

Explanation: if we have the recursive call inside the `print` call, we print the return value of the function, which is always going to be `None`, as it never returns anything else. So we have to move it outside.

Also, the boolean value of an empty list is `False`, so we can replace `lst == []` with `not lst`, as recommended by [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1):

list is a reserved word.

```
myList = [2,3,103, 8, 10]
for i in myList:
   print(i, end = (i>=100) and '\n' or ' ')
```

Comment: `print` as a function strongly suggests Python 3.x, so you can use `"\n" if i >= 100 else " "` instead of the dodgy `and` `or` thing.

Comment: True - I am more used to python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

After your function exists it returns `None`, which is why your print statements have the "None" in them. Just move the recursive call outside of print

```
    elif list[0] >= 100:
        function(my_list[1:])
        print(my_list[0], end='\n')
    else:
        function(my_list[1:])
        print(my_list[0], end='')
```